# What is the use of @EnableWebFlux annotation?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux

I just don't understand what is the real need of @EnableWebFlux. Because, I am able to write a simple 'helloworld' WebFlux REST API and was able to send request to controller without having to use that annotation.

I've already looked at the documentation but it is not clear for me.

Comment: I am aware of similar question in stackoverflow. But it did not answer my question. Thanks!

Comment: **What** _specifically_ is not clear?

Comment: Documentations : "Adding this annotation to an @Configuration class imports the Spring WebFlux configuration from WebFluxConfigurationSupport that enables use of annotated controllers and functional endpoints" . But annotated controllers (@Controller) works even without it right? Also what do they mean by functional endpoints?

Answer (score 6):

If you use `spring-boot-starter-webflux` the configuration is automatically done via `ReactiveWebServerFactoryAutoConfiguration` and `WebFluxAutoConfiguration`, so you don't need `@EnableWebFlux`

When you use `spring-webflux` without `spring-boot` you need to add `@EnableWebFlux` on a `@Configuration` class to import the Spring WebFlux configuration from `WebFluxConfigurationSupport`

Answer (score 1):

Spring boot uses auto configuration mechanism, which based on project's dependencies (classpath) creates default configurations for you. So when there is spring-boot-starter-webflux into your classpath   spring boot auto configuration mechanism automatically creates all required beans for this module to work. that's why your `@Controller` works out of the box.

Your project has a dependency on a module called spring-boot-autoconfigure and there is a class`org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.reactive.WebFluxAutoConfiguration` this `@Configuration` class is responsible on autoconfiguring webflux module. but this `@Configuration` works when other criteria(which are expressed by `@ConditionalOn...` annotations) are met.

```
@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
@ConditionalOnWebApplication(type = ConditionalOnWebApplication.Type.REACTIVE)
@ConditionalOnClass(WebFluxConfigurer.class)
@ConditionalOnMissingBean({ WebFluxConfigurationSupport.class })
@AutoConfigureAfter({ ReactiveWebServerFactoryAutoConfiguration.class, CodecsAutoConfiguration.class,
        ValidationAutoConfiguration.class })
@AutoConfigureOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE + 10)
public class WebFluxAutoConfiguration { ...
```

`@EnableWebFlux` just imports `DelegatingWebFluxConfiguration`

```
@Import(DelegatingWebFluxConfiguration.class)
public @interface EnableWebFlux {
}
```

> and this class A subclass of WebFluxConfigurationSupport that detects
>   and delegates to all beans of type WebFluxConfigurer allowing them to
>   customize the configuration provided by WebFluxConfigurationSupport.
>   This is the class actually imported by @EnableWebFlux.